# How to create a Copy button, similar to that on cdnjs.com?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

For example: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery

The `Copy` button on the right side. How does that work, how do I create it?

I can see by inspecting element that the button is `<button data-copy-type="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm copy-button">Copy</button>`, but I don't know how to find the functional code (I'm assuming javascript) that actually does the copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/

Let me show you how I found that:

1. Inspect the element
   [image]
2. On the upper right select the Event Listeners and look at the `click` event:
   [image]
3. Click on the `clipboard.min.js` file
   [image]
4. Here you see what library this is, and in this case even it's website.

<sup>(screenshots from Chrome, other browser have the same functionality, it just looks different or is in a different place)</sup>

Comment: Ah I see, so it isn't just a few lines of code, but rather a 2KB library! I'll have to reconsider adding this then... thanks for the screenshots, I've learned something new.

Comment: Well, the source code of the script is available. Usually the biggest bloat of such scripts is the "make it easy to use" part. I'm sure if you look through it the actual copy action does boil down to just a few lines.